# When should the "feature-request" be used?

Tags: support, tags, meta

When should a question be tagged [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)? Is it correct to use that tag for questions about tag requests, or should it be used only for requests of non implemented features?

My thought is that [support](/questions/tagged/support) should be used for questions like "I don't understand how this works on SE; can you explain it to me?" Leaving out [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion), the only obligatory tag that is left is [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be used when you are suggesting a new feature.

Tag requests should use the [retag-request](/questions/tagged/retag-request) tag along with either the [support](/questions/tagged/support) or [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) depending on whether you're certain about the retag or not (Thanks to Grace for pointing this out).

Comment: I'll tack this on here, although it applies equally to [George's answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87507/when-should-the-feature-request-be-used/87509#87509) as well: The required tag used with a retag-request is either [support] (if you're just asking for it to be done) or [discussion] (if you want to discuss whether it's a good idea).

Answer (score 3):

It should only be used when you're making a feature-request.

Discussion about tag requests (retagging) should have the [retag-request](/questions/tagged/retag-request) tag.