# How should I tag questions discussing the 'feature-request' tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, meta, feature-request-process

The [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) tag is used for:

> Proposals for new features on the site, or requests for a change to an existing feature

Now if I ask a question specifically about the [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) tag itself (like this very question!), is it okay to tag it with [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) too?

Comment: Is [meta-tag:feature-request-process] what you are looking for?

Answer (score 4):

I think it's better not to. I don't know whether or not there are automated tools that operate on the tags, but I'd bet there are (so the developers can keep track of each bug and feature request, see the status of each one, which will be implemented, etc.). I see the fact that at least one of {bug, feature request, discussion, support} is mandatory in each post as evidence of this, but I might be mistaken.

Adding that tag to posts that are not feature requests would pollute the result of those tools. IMHO it's better to just tag them as discussion, as you did. Just my two cents...

Looking at [this other question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/87507/177950) about the same tag, I believe you could use the tags [meta](/questions/tagged/meta) and [tags](/questions/tagged/tags) for that.

Comment: `[support]` would also be possible, of course.

Answer (score 3):

Since January 2014 (so more than a year *after* this question was asked), we have a dedicated tag for this: [feature-request-process](/questions/tagged/feature-request-process):

[image]

It's mostly used with [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) (if you want to discuss *about* feature requests) and [support](/questions/tagged/support) (if you want support *for* requesting a feature), but nothing stops you from suggesting a feature request *pertaining to* feature requests.

If you're familiar with Jira or other ticketing tools, "feature request" is in your case a domain/topic, not a ticket type. This very question could be tagged either [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion), or [support](/questions/tagged/support) (the distinction is not always made in practice, and there is a gray area).

Comment: ...and the user earned a Taxonomist badge due to questions I've been asking with this tag over the past couple months